# In Bootstrap, how to get fluid and different background colors in columns wrapped with container?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, background, row

Is it possible to get different and wider backgrounds for columns but its container keeps without modifications?

Take a look this image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by interchanging the bootstrap container, and the container responsible for rendering the background.

View the following snippet in full screen to get the idea. See how the container is inside the section, rather than the other way round for the other sections.

```css
.background {
  background-color: black;
}
#section1 {
  background-color: blue;
}
#section2 {
  background-color: white;
}
#section3 {
  background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhgAcBAKECAJk40Dh80P///////yH5BAEKAAIALAAAAACABwEAAAJCjI+py+0Po5y02ouz3rz7D4biSJbmiabqyrbuKwHyTNf2jef6zvf+DwwKh8Si8YhMKpfMpvMJjUqn1Kr1is1qt74CADs=);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: center top;
}
#section4 {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="background">
  <div class="container">
    <section id="section1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla blandit aliquam eros, non commodo augue efficitur sit amet. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin gravida egestas tristique. Phasellus eget hendrerit dolor.</section>
    <section id="section2">Ut mollis nunc aliquet libero scelerisque cursus. Sed velit felis, commodo tincidunt tortor ut, placerat lacinia ante. Pellentesque eu est vel magna facilisis dignissim. Fusce varius est viverra erat bibendum placerat.</section>
  </div>
  <section id="section3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">Nunc laoreet turpis sit amet mi condimentum semper. Fusce sit amet rutrum arcu, eget facilisis risus.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce malesuada felis quis massa suscipit ultrices.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="container">
    <section id="section4">Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Etiam vestibulum efficitur placerat. Integer egestas dapibus neque vel consectetur. Mauris eleifend commodo risus id pharetra.</section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With your approach I don't get different backgrounds for the row. My idea is to get different background color for each column but this background should span until to browser borders.

Comment: @gfdesign One simple way would be to attach a single image to the background of the section and fix it's position to center. However this will only work with equal width columns. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank for giving your approach. FYI, I've seen in other sites they use the different background colors through some divs with position:fixed along with z-index properties. I'll try by this path. Regards